# How to install Psyco: Getting "No Python installation found in Registry"

Tags: installation, python

I want to install [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) on my Windows 7 x64. I have Python 3 installed but i am getting the error

> No Python Installation Found in Registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install 64-bit Python 3? Psyco is not available for 64-bit Python. Python puts registry entries at different locations for 32- vs 64-bit installations, as explained [at their bugtracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue9809). If you've installed 64-bit Python, Psyco won't find it since it is looking for a 32-bit installation.

Answer (score 0):

Psyco is no longer supported, as said on their official site:

> 12 March 2012
>
> Psyco is unmaintained and dead. Please look at PyPy for the state-of-the-art in JIT compilers for Python.

For details, see: http://psyco.sourceforge.net/.